# Grep XYZ and display line with only X + regex

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I have this list of services `list_services`:

```
user@10006
user@10007
user@10008
user@10009
user@1006
user@509
user@512
user@513
user@519
```

I wanted to know if it is possible to do :

```
for service in $list_services :
    grep $service /tmp/file
```

and match with something i can put in this /tmp/file (maybe with regex), in any case.

Thx

I've tried

```
grep "^$service$" /tmp/file
```

with `user@.` and `user@\d` and `user@*` in /tmp/file

and

```
grep "$service" /tmp/file
```

with a line `user@.` and `user@\d` and `user@*` in /tmp/file

Comment: Can you please show example input and example desired output?

Comment: The desired output is what i am supposed to put in the file to match the grep $service
I don't really know it is possible to do it in this way (I know the other way would be very easy to do)

Comment: Maybe `grep -E '^service@[0-9]+$' /tmp/file`?

Comment: I think I've explained my issue very bad lol... (My bad ^^')
It is possible to have a same output if I do "grep user@10006" /tmp/file and "grep user@512" /tmp/file ?
If yes, what I've to put in this /tmp/file ?

Comment: The string `service` does not appear in the file you have posted. It is not clear to me what result you expect from your example.

Comment: I edited the ask, I hope it is clearer now
I apologize for the bad explanations

Comment: Can you show an example of `/tmp/file` and what you want the result to be?

Comment: An example of the /tmp/file is the question haha.
I can give an example :

grep user@10006
> user

grep user@509
> user

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `/tmp/file` contains the regular expressions, not the lines that need to be matched with a regexp. To get the regexp from a file, use `-f filename`.

So I think you want

```
grep -f /tmp/file <<<"$list_services"
```